# How to redirect or serve different page if page getting more requests in apache server

Tags: php, apache, traffic

I had problem that particular pages were getting more load sometimes, causing internal server error .. is there any way to identify particular page is getting more requests in this particular instance time, and then serve another page for that request.

Comment: Normally this would be done by a load balancer, which would have a list of servers and would either split the load evenly based on number of requests(incredibly basic and vulnerable to the application servers failing and still being served requests) or response time(more advanced, when a server stops responding it's average load time goes up and it get's served less content until it starts responding again). Most load balancers also support a method of specifying that a particular server should only be used if the average load time across the other servers becomes too high.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mod_qos` Apache module to adjust server response based on various activities.

A common strategy is to rate-limit the resource intensive application to assure availability of other applications.  The module can either send a HTTP error code or a 302 redirect if limits are reached.

In practice, getting limits correct can be challenging and it may be better to spend your efforts optimizing the code on the script.

I recommend limiting `mod_qos` rules to just the application that is causing issues.  Transactional web applications, AJAX and other apps may have problems if you interrupt the normal flow of events with `mod_qos`.  So be sure to test.

For a simpler solution, there is `mod_limitipconn`.

This tool simply rates limits requests.  More useful in DoS than specific application limiting.

References

[Mod QOS Documentation](http://opensource.adnovum.ch/mod_qos/)

[Mod Limit iP Conn](http://dominia.org/djao/limitipconn.html)